# How to get XAML Designer to run my custom UI element's initialization code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I've got a custom subclass of Grid (completely in C#, no XAML for the subclass itself):

```
public class AView : Grid
{
    // ...
}
```

It works fine in XAML Designer for the main window of the app where I use it.

OnRender() is getting called by the XAML Designer, because any custom drawing that I do in there shows up nicely in the Designer.

But where do I put initialization code that XAML Designer will run?

For example, I want vertical alignment to be VerticalAlignment.Bottom, but when I put it in the constructor, the setting isn't honored in the properties window of the designer:

```
public class AView : Grid
{
    public AView ()
    {
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

So where should it go?

Comment: See [Control authoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). There should be a default control Style in Themes/Generic.xaml

Comment: Isn't there a PrepareForXAMLDesigner() method or something like that? Where does initialization happen when the XAML Designer is rendering a custom UI element?